# CSS dynamic absolute path with HTTTPs

Tags: css

I have a solution which uses AWS Cloudfront CDN for static files (like: images, js and css). In the application, some pages uses HTTP and HTTPS requests. This way, my CSS files has **absolute paths** to CDN and has to dynamically change the prefix HTTP to HTTPS when using HTTPS requests, otherwise the HTTPS breaks.

For example:
When I access http://mydomain.com/page-a.php, the CSS loaded is:

```
    body{
      background: url("http://aws.cloudfront.com/image-for-page-a.png");
    }
```

But, when I access https://mydomain.com/page-a.php (note the HTTPS request), the CSS has to load the image in the cloudfront HTTPS domain:

```
    body{
      background: url("https://aws.cloudfront.com/image-for-page-a.png");
    }
```

How do I make this request change dynamically from HTTP to HTTPS in the CSS file?
Any suggestions on the architecture are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need absolute paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scheme relative URLs:

```
body{
  background: url("//aws.cloudfront.com/image-for-page-a.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic nature of pushing the http or https based URL need to be written in your application. You have pick the http or https in the run-time then prepare the css or inject the css and then serve it via the application.

The is kind of tricky or rather mundane to implement. The better approach which I would suggest it to modify your application in a such a way to make use of https based URL.

After you have implemented this, chances are your main application could be HTTP based and the js / png / media could be delivered via. https. Tomorrow if you decide to make all your application https based, you don't need to touch this module again.